# delete rows based on references to other tables in a mysql database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql

I have a database with the following hierarchy.

- A dataset can have multiple scans (`foreign key scan.id_dataset -> dataset.id`)
- A scan can have multiple labels (`foreign key label.id_scan -> scan.id`)
- A label has a labeltype (`foreign key label.id_labeltype-> labeltype.id`)
- The dataset, scan and labeltype tables all have a `name` column

I want to delete a label based on the names of the dataset, scan and labeltype. Here is my working code using the python mysql-connector:

```py
def delete_by_labeltype(
    self, dataset_name: str, scan_name, labeltype_name: str
) -> int:
    sql = (
        "DELETE l.* FROM label l "
        "INNER JOIN labeltype lt "
        "ON l.id_labeltype = lt.id "
        "WHERE lt.name = %s AND l.id_scan = ("
        "   SELECT scan.id FROM scan "
        "   INNER JOIN dataset "
        "   ON dataset.id = scan.id_dataset "
        "   WHERE scan.name = %s AND dataset.name = %s"
        ");"
    )

    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            sql,
            (
                labeltype_name,
                scan_name,
                dataset_name,
            ),
        )
        self.connection.commit()
        return cursor.rowcount
```

The function is within a class handling access to the label table so connection is already established (and later closed correctly).
I am simply wondering if the query is the best way to do this, since I am not working with SQL too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nit: For consistency with `scan.id` I would
choose the column name `scan_id`
instead of `id_scan`, meh, whatever.

Kudos on correctly using bind variables,
keeping Little Bobby Tables out of your hair.
The `%s`, `%s`, `%s` in the query don't seem
especially convenient, for matching up
against {label, scan, ds} names in a `tuple`.
Prefer to use three distinct names,
and pass in a `dict`.
If you do that habitually,
then when a query grows to mention half a dozen
parameters, and some newly hired maintenance engineer
adds a seventh one, you won't be sorry.

And I like the explicit COMMIT.

---

> best way to do this?

Looks good to me.
I didn't hear you complaining about "too slow!"
or reliability / flakiness.
You didn't say that EXPLAIN PLAN showed
some index was being ignored.

Including an
[ERD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)
entity-relationship diagram would have been helpful,
or at least the CREATE TABLE DDL including FK definitions.
Let me try to organize your prose.
Here's what I heard.

- label --> labeltype
- label --> scan --> dataset

It's not obvious to me why `scan` and `dataset`
should be in a subquery rather than at same level -- it
just arbitrarily came out that way, no biggie.

The `l.id_scan = (` fragment suggests to me
that there's enough UNIQUE indexes on {scan, ds} `name`
to ensure we get no more than one result row from the subquery,
else you would have mentioned `l.id_scan IN ( ...`.
It's perfectly fine the way it is.
Maybe JOIN label against labeltype and also against scan?
(And then scan against ds.)

If I was chicken, I would do all the JOINing in SELECT statements,
obtain an `id` that I could do a sanity check on,
and *then* send a simple DELETE single row command.
But you're braver than me, and it works, so that's cool.

When reasoning about complex JOINs I often find it convenient
to bury some of the complexity behind a VIEW.
Minimally you would want to define a `scan_dataset_v` view
so you never have to type the name of the "dataset" table again.

```
CREATE VIEW scan_dataset_v AS
  SELECT s.*, ds.*
  FROM scan s
  JOIN dataset ds  ON ds.id = s.id_dataset;
```

Now `label` has just two relationships to worry about.
(And, the `*` stars probably have at least
one conflicting column name -- just write them all out.
Absent the DDL, I don't know what all the columns are.)

You might possibly find it convenient to produce
a view that JOINs them both to `label`,
and another that JOINs `labeltype` to `label`.
It just saves some typing during interactive queries.
There's no efficiency hit -- think of it as the
backend doing a macro expansion before issuing the query.

---

Summary: Any improvements? Nope, not really, LGTM.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed overview!